# Doctrine 2 - No Metadata Classes to process by orm:generate-repositories

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to generate entity repositories and getting such message

**No Metadata Classes to process**

I'd tracked down that use of

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
and 
@ORM\Table
is not working properly.

If i change all @ORM\Table to just @Table(and other annotations) - it start to work, but I really don't want to get it that way as it should work with @ORM annotation.

I followed instructions from page below with no luck. I know I'm close but missing something with file paths or namespaces. Please help.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html

Does anyone had such problem? What I missing?

cli-config,

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

define('APPLICATION_ENV', "development");
error_reporting(E_ALL);



//AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php");
//AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace("Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint", "Doctrine/Symfony");
//AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace("Annotations", "/Users/ivv/workspaceShipipal/shipipal/codebase/application/persistent/");

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine');
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__ . '/application/');
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Proxies', __DIR__ . '/application/persistent');
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/application/persistent/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses((APPLICATION_ENV == "development"));


$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(__DIR__ . "/application/persistent/Entities"));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
} else {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
}

$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);


$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'dbname'   => 'mydb',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => ''

);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
$platform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
     'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
     'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

User.php(working version, initially it was as described, @Table was @ORM\Table and other annotations similar had @ORM\ part like @ORM\Column etc)

```
<?php
namespace Entities;


use Doctrine\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @Table(name="user")
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\User")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $userName
     *
     * @Column(name="userName", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @Column(name="email", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var text $bio
     *
     * @Column(name="bio", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $bio;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue just now. I'll post an answer if I can find a solution.

Comment: posting the code of the entity and reader, and directory structure might help getting an accurate answer.

Comment: added sourcec code for cli config and User.php

Comment: wow @450 reps bounty :o, wish I knew enough doctrine to help you :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT 3:**

If it matters, I'm using Doctrine 2.2.1. Anyway, I'm just adding a bit more information on this topic.

I dug around the Doctrine\Configuration.php class to see how newDefaultAnnotationDriver created the AnnotationDriver. The method begins on line 125, but the relevant part is line 145 to 147 if you're using the latest version of the Common library.

```
} else {
    $reader = new AnnotationReader();
    $reader->setDefaultAnnotationNamespace('Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\\');
}
```

I couldn't actually find the setDefaultAnnotationNamespace method in AnnotationReader class. So that was weird. But I'm assuming it sets the namespace Doctrine\Orm\Mapping, so that annotations in that namespace don't need to be prefixed. Hence the error since it seems the doctrine cli tool generates the entities differently. I'm not sure why that is.

You'll notice in my answer below, I didn't call the setDefaultAnnotationNamespace method.

One a side note, I noticed in your User Entity class that you have `use Doctrine\Mapping as ORM`. Shouldn't the generated file create `use Doctrine\Orm\Mapping as ORM;`? Or maybe that is a typo.

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, I found the problem. Apparently it has to do with the default annotation driver used by the \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration class.

So instead of using `$config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(...)`, you need to instantiate a new AnnotationReader, a new AnnotationDriver, and then set it in your Configuration class.

Example:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php");
$reader = new AnnotationReader();
$driverImpl = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver($reader, array(__DIR__ . "/application/persistent/Entities"));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
```

**EDIT2** (Here the adjustments added to your cli-config.php):

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

define('APPLICATION_ENV', "development");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine');
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__ . '/application/');
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Proxies', __DIR__ . '/application/persistent');
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/application/persistent/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');

$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses((APPLICATION_ENV == "development"));


 //Here is the part that needs to be adjusted to make allow the ORM namespace in the annotation be recognized

#$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(__DIR__ . "/application/persistent/Entities"));

AnnotationRegistry::registerFile("Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php");
$reader = new AnnotationReader();
$driverImpl = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver($reader, array(__DIR__ . "/application/persistent/Entities"));
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

//End of Changes

if (APPLICATION_ENV == "development") {
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();
} else {
   $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache();
}

$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);


$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'dbname'   => 'mydb',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => ''
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
$platform = $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform();
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

Comment: You are a life saver.  I had used an old Symfony project to generate the entity mappings directly from the database tables and just copied the entity classes over to this new Doctrine project.  Your answer was spot on.  I did a find "@ORM\" and replace "@" on my entity classes and voila.  Now I actually have entity metadata showing in the doctrine console.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into the same problem that you've got. I am using Doctrine 2.4. I can fix this issue by doing this in the config file. I am not sure if this works for versions < 2.3.

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/entities"), $isDevMode, null, null, FALSE); // just add null, null, false at the end
```

Below is the documentation for the method createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration. I have just dig into the source code. By default it uses a simple annotation reader, which means you don't need to have ORM\ in front of your annotation, you can do @Entities instead of @ORM\Entities. So all you need to do here is to disable it using simple annotation reader.

```
/**
 * Creates a configuration with an annotation metadata driver.
 *
 * @param array   $paths
 * @param boolean $isDevMode
 * @param string  $proxyDir
 * @param Cache   $cache
 * @param bool    $useSimpleAnnotationReader
 *
 * @return Configuration
 */
public static function createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array $paths, $isDevMode = false, $proxyDir = null, Cache $cache = null, $useSimpleAnnotationReader = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

As Gohn67 said.. u have to instanciate a new reader.

I had the same issue but with Zend.
The problem its in the reader and not in the driver.

Ex:
if i use "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader" as reader i had to write all my annotation without the @ORM

But if i use "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader" i need to put @ORM on the annotations to get work

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any references to `@ORM\Table` anywhere but in Symfony2 projects. In the documentation it's always referenced as `@Table`

I know that it works in sf2 (I'm using it there). Is it possible that it's a bug with a vanilla install from Doctrine?

Comment: I don't know why but the namespace is ommitted in the documentation.

Comment: I think the documentation is not up to date (which is frustrating).

Answer (score 0):

The most possible explanation is, as you stated, there is something wrong with include(namespace issue, path issue etc.) either in reader or in the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue (although the other way around), when upgrading from Doctrine 2.0 to Doctrine 2.1 (or 2.2). For Doctrine 2.0 my annotations using @Table worked fine, but after upgrade it started to complain that annotation was not loaded. I suggest you give Doctrine 2.2 a go, in order to use @ORM\Table

Answer (score 0):

Noticed a small discrepancy...

In your Entity your using;

```
use Doctrine\Mapping as ORM;
```

Instead of:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

Maybe that will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in bootstrap.php (required by cli-config.php)

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
```

this "src" was not pointing to the correct source folder.

Answer (score 0):

[English]

Review the *bootstrap.php* file and where you configure the orm doctrine, you change the annotations by yaml:

```
/* Configuring by annotacions*/
//$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);

/* Configuring by yaml*/
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yml"), $isDevMode);
```

Note: the path /config/yml must exist.

[Espanish]

Revisar el archivo bootstrap y donde configuras el orm doctrine, cambia las anotaciones por yaml:

/* Configuring by annotacions*/
    //$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(**DIR**."/src"), $isDevMode);

```
/* Configuring by yaml*/
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yml"), $isDevMode);
```

Importante: el directorio /config/yml debe existir.

Answer (score 0):

```
..

$generator = new EntityGenerator();
$generator->setAnnotationPrefix('');   // edit: quick fix for No Metadata Classes to process
$generator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(true); // only update if class already exists
//$generator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(true);    // this will overwrite the existing classes
$generator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);

$generator->setAnnotationPrefix('ORM\\'); // <<---------------|

$generator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
$generator->generate($metadata, __DIR__ . '/Entities');

..
```